# Eloquent ORM find by id and add where clause to a relationship model

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Hey guys how you doing? 
I'm trying to simply find by id and at the same time guarantee that a column from a relationship table is with a value.
I tried a few things but nothing works.

```
$tag = Tag::find($id)->whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->where('status','=', 1);
})->get();
```

Also:

```
$tag = Tag::whereHas('posts', function($q) {
    $q->where('status','=', 1);
})->where('id','=', $id)->get();
```

Can you help me?

It is a simple thing but I can't manage to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to read on `Eloquent` docs. Learn what's `find`, `first`, `get` for that matter.

Your code does what you need, and more (a bit wrong though) ;)

```
$tag = Tag::find($id) // here you fetched the Tag with $id
        ->whereHas('posts', function($q){  // now you start building another query
    $q->where('status','=', 1);
})->get();  // here you fetch collection of Tag models that have related posts.status=1
```

So, this is what you want:

```
$tag = Tag::whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->where('status','=', 1);
})->find($id);
```

It will return `Tag` model or `null` if there is no row matching that `where` clause OR given `$id`.

Comment: The code didn't worked... Return null and I have the tag... This is the only way it works:                                                    [code] $tag = Tag::find($id);
        $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($id)
        {
            $q->where('id', '=', $id);

        })->where('status', '=', '1')->get();

Comment: What you pasted is completely different query. The one I gave you may return null, like stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) ?

You can do this:

```
$tag = Tag::where('status', '=', 1)
           ->where('id', '=', 1, $id)
           ->get();
```

Comment: The status field is in Post model... They have a many to many relationship... I can get the posts from a particular tag but what I want is to get just the posts with status = 1

Comment: if you want just the posts with status =1, why don't you use `Post::where('status', '=', '1')` ?

Comment: Because I need the posts from a specific tag id

Comment: Do you have one to many relationship between the `tag` and the `posts`?